# Positive & Negative Polarity Items, and Interrogatives

Tags: syntax, negation, questions

There are certain items in some languages that tend to occur largely in negative clauses. In English, one such item might be the word *ever*:

- *I have ever been to Paris.
- I haven't ever been to Paris.

There are other items that tend to only occur in positive clauses, for example the item *somewhat*:

- *He didn't smell somewhat.
- He smelled somewhat.

The former are often referred to as Negative Polarity Items (NPI's), the latter as Positive Polarity Items (PPI's).

Many, if not most, NPI and PPI items can occur in questions:

- Have you ever been to Paris?
- Was he somewhat smelly?

What I'd like to know is if there is a  group of items that tends to only occur in question/interrogative environments?

If there is, is there an established term for such items? Are there any lists of such items in various languages, or perhaps in English?

I can think of only one such English item which seems to behave like this, namely *by any chance*:

- *He was there by any chance.
- *He was not there by any chance.
- He wasn't there by any chance?
- Was he there by any chance?

One swallow, of course, doesn’t make a summer.

Comment: Congratulations on finding a Q-polarity expression.  Parenthetical "I wonder" seems similar.

Comment: Your argument that *somewhat* is a PPI doesn't convince me. A problem with x"He didn't smell somewhat" is that it entails "not somewhat" as a quantifier. This is not idiomatic for me, but this doesn't preclude *somewhat* in questions. Cf *almost*: x"They're not almost ready" "Are they almost ready?" [where the asker knows that they are not completely ready].

Comment: @RosieF But PPI's aren't excluded from questions (or for that matter conditional antecedents), as explicitly stated in my post!

Comment: Hmmm. *_Where was he, by any chance?_ *_How bad does he smell, somewhat?_

Comment: @jlawler I don't think that people [Huddleston & Pullum etc] who analyse *somewhat* as a PPI say it can occur in every non-negative environment (in fact *CamGEL* go into a lot of detail about the details of when such items can and can't). On my part, it seems that *by any chance* only regularly occurs in polar interrogative/conditional protasis environments (at least from my summary investigation on Monday of all the *by any chances* in COCA). But, of course, that doesn't mean that there aren't restrictions on the semantic/pragmatic contexts in which it can occur, or its syntactic position!

Comment: @jlawler But as you are a primary  go-to source for much of the NPI lit that I have been collecting this week, I suspect you're partly  toying with me :)

Comment: Toying with the idea, anyway. Never thought of it. The reason why questions allow NPIs is because the nature of a question includes the possibility of negation. But it's only one possibility, so PPIs are also OK. _By any chance_ itself contains an NPI, and it refers to that possibility.

Comment: @jlawler So that's probably the same reason NPI's and PPI's occur in conditional protases too, right? There's a possibility of negation, but it's only one of the two possibilities.